# How to solve the vector differential equation of projectile with air resistance?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-analysis

I want to find the general solution of the following **vector** DE:
$$\dot{\mathbf v}+k|\mathbf v|\mathbf v=\mathbf g$$
where $\mathbf v=\dot{\mathbf r}$, $\mathbf g,k$ being constants. This is the equation describing the projectile motion with air resistance $\propto v^2$. In one dimension, this can be easily solved with separation of variable: it ends up with an arctanh function. But this stops working in any higher dimensions.

I can also solve the case in which resistance $\propto v$ by integrating factor.

**But how to solve the equation above analytically?** OR is it impossible?

PS: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3090582/air-resistance-in-projectile-motion) is a good answer about linear drag, but it does not address quadratic drag.

Comment: You can't. There was some big ado (of the wonderchild type) about a first integral, but that removes only one degree of freedom, and any numerical simulation of the other 3 can as well or better done on the original system.

Comment: @LutzLl What do you mean by "a first integral" and "original system" etc...? Could you write an answer to explain that to me? Thanks a lot!